# How can I make the Xubuntu window title bar transparent?

Tags: xubuntu, transparency

I'm looking to make the Xubuntu window title bar transparent (something like Windows Aero).

How can I do this? My taskbar is already transparent-ish by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I finally made this work:

Open `Window Manager Tweaks`. Go to the `Compositor` tab. Lower the `Opacity of window decorations`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal emulator (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) and type: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra`

   This program was designed for the unity desktop environment however
   it is compatible with xfce, the default desktop for Xubuntu, [as
   this link assures](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compiz#XFCE) , the command will install the program as well
   as a set of extra plugins that will allow us to perform the action.
2. Run the `ccsm` program, go to accessibility and open the
   opacity,brightness and saturation section.
3. Enable the section.
4. Choose the opacity button and select the command you want to use to increase the opacity.

Comment: No problem, remember to validate if it does work

Comment: Nope, didn't work. (No option to select window bar transparency).

Comment: Compiz was there way before unity, so it's designed for unity is not true